# How to use LaTeX fonts to format the text?

Tags: fonts, formatting

Are there fonts in LaTeX equivalent to those of Microsoft Office ("Times New Romans, Veranda, Courrier ... ") ? If yes, how can we use them ? Which package contains them?

Comment: If you have them as TrueType fonts, you can use them with `xelatex` and the `fontspec` package.

Comment: If you use xelatex then you can use exactly the Windows system fonts available to Word. `fontspec` is the package you then need (theer are lots of examples on this site look for fontspec or xetex tags

Comment: Yes, you are right, I donwloaded the official documentation of `fontspec` and I found everything I need there. Thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina perhaps an answer? or a duplicate? or too localized? you decide :) to the OP (begueradj): welcome to the site!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina how about: [How can I get Latex to use the fonts that are already on my PC via Xetex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3101)

Comment: @cmhughes Sounds like a good candidate. I've already started the closing process. I'll delete my comments shortly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The question is not a duplicate to a question that limits the TeX engine to XeTeX. In the general case, there are other options (psnfss, TeX Gyre).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Hmmm... you're right. Do you have another candidate for a real duplicate od perhaps should we reopen this and provide a proper answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I think, it should be reopened. I have not found a real duplicate.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This one is pretty close: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex Also  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46/how-do-i-use-an-opentype-font-with-my-latex-document/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. None of those really answers the *original* question which concerns the availability of equivalents within LaTeX which I take to mean already set up as part of a standard TeX installation. The answer linked on installing ttf fonts for use with pdfTeX is, in my opinion, rather poor. (Even for MiKTeX users but more so for TeX Live users.) There are various methods for installing ttf fonts, just as there are for installing type1 fonts, for use with pdfTeX (and TeX in the case of type1). However, entirely automated procedures don't usually do a great job...

Comment: @cfr Yeah, I suppose you're right.

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad, I'm afraid.