# Using Windows font in XeLaTex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am currently having issues trying to use different fonts in my documents.

I read that if I want to use fonts directly installed in the `Windows/Fonts` directory I should compile the document using `Xelatex`.

Although I found some questions on this topic, like [How can I get Latex to use the fonts that are already on my PC via Xetex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/how-can-i-get-latex-to-use-the-fonts-that-are-already-on-my-pc-via-xetex)
, I could not get it to work.

I would like to use a callygraphic font like this one: [Anteiku](https://www.dafont.com/anteiku.font?text=Anteiku&l[]=10&l[]=1&back=new). I can use it in Word without problems, but with `Xelatex` I get the message `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape` `EU1/Anteiku/m/n'` `undefined`.
It is not working even if I use the complete font name I find in the `Windows/Fonts` folder (in this case `Anteiku Normale`).

You can find here below a Minimal (Not) Working Example, showing the error message I get:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{Anteiku}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

{\myfont My text}

Your text

\end{document}
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: The command is `\newfontfamily\myfont{Anteiku}`. Btw: EU1 indicates that your tex system is quite old.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your help. I tried the command you indicated but now I get error messages like `The font "Anteiku" cannot be found.`. Do you think it is because my tex system is old? Could you give me some instructions on how to update it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated my tex system as you suggested, and now I am able to use Windows fonts without problems. If you want to write an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again for your help!